# How to identify if an input box value is a mask?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

How to identify if input box value being passed to another page is a mask?

I have a code like this:

```
number = Request("Cnumber")   'value from an input box
```

Output of `Request("Cnumber")` is like this:

```
xxxxxxxxxxxx5555
```

I want to check the value of `number` something like this:

```
if number(having an X value on the left) then
    use another value
end if
```

How would I apply it on the `If` statement condition?

Comment: Is it as simple as `If Left(Request("Cnumber"), 1) = "x" Then` or am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@John](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37425474/how-to-identify-if-an-input-box-value-is-mask-in-asp-classic#comment62358196_37425474) pointed out, just check the first character at the beginning of the string:

```
If Left(Request("Cnumber"), 1) = "x" Then
    'use another value
End If
```

Add `LCase` if you want to make the comparison case-insensitive:

```
If LCase(Left(Request("Cnumber"), 1)) = "x" Then
    'use another value
End If
```